# Is there an Erlang implementation for Android?

Tags: android, erlang

I know of many languages that can be used on Android to build apps, most of them JVM-related, but I have not been able to find an Erlang implementation for it.

Is there a port of Erlang for Android?

If there is not a good port available, how would one go about making such a port?

Comment: // , This came up in the Erlang mailing list, a while back: http://erlang.org/pipermail/erlang-questions/2014-May/078954.html

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Try this: http://code.google.com/p/erlang4android/

You need to install the new APK, which can be used to download the actual Erlang binaries.

This app installs a small version of Erlang (i.e. erlang_R16.zip) for use with SL4A.

First install SL4A, then this app, then run this app to install Erlang/OTP and use SL4A to run your Erlang code.

Using the app you can add OTP applications from a repository.

From the main screen you can select the menu option "Settings" to specify extra command line arguments that will be used when Erlang is started. For example, to start distribution, specify "-name myandroid@example.org -setcookie mysecretcookie" (without the quotes and with relevant values).

updated

Here is a good instruction regarding [building Erlang for Android](http://bluishcoder.co.nz/2015/06/21/building-erlang-for-android.html)

Comment: I was looking for something that required a bit less configuration by the end user to get off the ground, but this could still prove very useful.

Comment: // , Sometimes one app can "bootstrap" the configuration of another.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the android app "Exec Erlang":
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.mlauer.erlangtest
[image: Screenshot ExecErlang]