# how to write an android app with languages other than java

Tags: java, android

my title is a little different than what i try to say, i couldnt exactly tell what i mean.

as far as i know we develop android apps with android studio(and there were support for other ide s like eclipse before) you code it and make a gui app with drag and drop.

recently i tried to open source code of few android apps like whatsapp. i extracted the classes.dex file and checked the source code. it was written with java. but when i google "whatsapp" it says it is written with erlang.

my question is, how the code written with erlang turns to a java code? as far as i know you can make android apps with c++ too. since we dont have a translator for languages, how is this being possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

WhatsApps backend is written in Erlang, not the app
https://www.quora.com/Is-WhatsApp-fully-written-in-Erlang

Android uses the Java Virtual Machine (JVM) runtime. To run Android apps on a phone you either need to write them in a JVM language (Java, Kotlin, Scala), or write them in another language and that has a rumtime interpreter on the device (Javascript + Android Webview, Flutter + Flutter Runtime)

You can write your app in just c++, but then you won't have any of the Android SDK available to you. You'd have to rebuild the entire view plaform (among other things). Flutter does this.

If you have more specific questions I'd be happy to answer them

Comment: so the server is written with erlang, and client must be with a jvm language? is there any other jvm languages or only these 3?

Comment: Correct. You can write android apps in erlang, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18542438/is-there-an-erlang-implementation-for-android  But you'll have the issue that pure c++ would have, in that you'd have no access to the android SDK

Comment: i edited my comment but seems you didnt notice it, is there any other jvm languages

Comment: thanks, i see there are many languages. is there a specific reason c++ doesnt have support for it?

Comment: The Android SDK is written in Java. You need to use a JVM compatible language to interact with it.